# Extension : Multi-highlight on safari

Tags: safari, applescript, google-chrome, highlights

I'm not sure this topic is appropriate for this forum but I'm looking for a Multi-highlight extension or AppleScript for Safari.

I using Multi-highlight for Google Chrome at the moment but I would rather do use Safari.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-highlight/pfgfgjlejbbpfmcfjhdmikihihddeeji

any idea of a similar extension or a way to implement this in a script?

Comment: So...'any idea' as in you want something like Multi-highlight for Safari? Please be specific.

Comment: Doubtful. Safari has just and handful of extensions. Maybe try a PDF reader?